# Is Ansible Turing Complete?

Tags: ansible, turing-complete

Ansible offers many filters and conditionals. As far as I can tell; it should be possible to implement an Ansible playbook that executes a set of tasks that achieve the same outcome as a Turing Complete language. So, is it Turing Complete?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is.

1. Ansible can generate yaml files and run itself upon it (both may be done as `local_action`), which is a rough equivalent of `eval()` function.
2. Ansible can create lists and iterate over them. Together with `include_role` it opens ability to run arbitrary complex code within loop (with conditions).
3. Together with `until` keyword it allows to create classic while/until loop.
4. `block` with `where` statement allows branching. Even within loops.

Moreover, playbook-related plugins are counted as a valid way to extend playbook, therefore they provide full python features.